# How to check biggest consecutive numbers in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to find the largest consecutive numbers in a list and append them to new list.

`my_list = [97, 98, 97, 98, 99, 97, 98, 97]`

I tried using while loop but when incremented, it isn't appending some numbers.

```
final_list = []
j = 0
while j < (len(my_list) - 1):
    if my_list[j] + 1 == my_list[j + 1]:
        final_list.append(my_list[j])
        final_list.append(my_list[j + 1])
        j += 2
    else:
        j += 1    
print(final_list)
```

The expected output must be 
final_list = [97,98,99]

But my output is

`final_list = [97,98]`

Comment: You will probably get another problem if you start with a number thats not the smallest one (for example [100, 97, ...] or if you add [ ..., 1,2, ..] somewhere inbetween because your code only checks if j and j+1 of the original list are consecutive.

You need to compare the values in my_list to the last value of new_list to actually get a consecutive list. But then you still have a problem if your first number isn´t the smallest one so you need to find the smallest number first to get the real starting point.
It gets quite tricky if you want to extract multiple consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `consecutive_groups` from `more_itertools` module:

```
max([list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(my_list)], key=len)
```

**Example**:

```
import more_itertools as mit

my_list = [97, 98, 97, 98, 99, 97, 98, 97]

print(max([list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(my_list)], key=len))
# [97, 98, 99]
```

*Note*: Since this is a third-party module, you need to install before trying out - pip install more_itertools.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution without an external tool:

```
    my_list = [97, 98, 97, 1, 2, 100, 98, 99, 97, 98, 97];
    #sort list max to min
    my_list.sort(reverse = True)
    # take largest number as starting point
    last_item = my_list[0]
    new_list = [last_item]
    # loop through list for every item to assure that we dont stop too soon
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        for number in my_list:
            # compare the current number with the last number inserted to new_list
            # if its smaller we add it to the list and update the last item
            if number == last_item-1:
                new_list.append(number)
                last_item = number
    print(new_list)
```

Please note that this is probably not the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Find the indices where difference between consecutive elements `!= 1` using `np.where` and `np.diff` (returns a tuple, get the first element of tuple which is an array of indices), add `1` to each element to get the endpoints for `np.split`.
Find the largest array from the resulting list using `max(list,key=len)`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_list = [97, 98, 97, 98, 99, 97, 98, 97]
>>> max(np.split(my_list,np.where(np.diff(my_list) != 1)[0]+1),key=len)
array([97, 98, 99])
```